# Stackpanel overlap image

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` configured with columns. In first column I have an `Image`, in second `StackPanel` with `TextBlocks`, and in the rest columns other TextBlocks.

When I run app I see Image and this others TextBlocks. The problem is that StackPanel overlaps on Image (TextBlock's content appears over Image) and part of content appears under other columns in Grid. I add `MinWidth` to Image and Stackpanel but it did not solve the problem :/ 

It looks like the Image doesn't have width, so StackPanel overlaps it, and StackPanel also doesn't have enough width so it hides under other columns.

Example, all TextBlocks are bound to data source:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" MinWidth="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" MinWidth="120" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Textblock />
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions> needs to be just <Grid.ColumnDefinition> (no s after Column) and its not closed either

Comment: I not copy it from code, but retype myself so sry for misspelled :/

Comment: post your code or get closer to what your code is, using your example as best as i can assume what you meant works fine with the image, there is no overlap.

Comment: Are you setting fixed widths on any of your row elements, like the Image or TextBlocks?  That may be your problem.  You can try setting the image to scale (see `Stretch`) and enabling text wrapping on your text blocks.  You could also wrap each "cell" in a `Border` or some other container with `ClipToBounds="True"`.

Comment: Have you try setting the horizontal alignment to stretch?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared columns with a fixed width.  It seems apparent that your content in those columns is wider than the column widths that you have declared.

Adding `MinWidth` to the `Image` and `StackPanel` will not help in this case.  You would need to set the `MaxWidth` of those two items to prevent them from being wider than the declared column widths.

Setting fixed column widths defeats one of the purposes of using WPF in the first place.  WPF, when implemented properly will allow your user interface to scale nicely when the window size changes.

Shown below are column definitions that would be more appropriate for WPF:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="4.8*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The values shown above for column width will give the same ratio of widths as the fixed values in your example, but they are scalable when the window size changes.